# Cómo puedo reenviar un formulario automáticamente?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

En "Vista 1" tengo una tabla:

```
Entrega     Orden   Remito
11111       1111    11111
22222       2222    22222
33333       3333    33333
```

La columna "Entrega" son enlaces que envían un valor a "Vista 2" con un mediante un `HttpPost`.

Cuando quiero volver a "Vista 1", la web me muestra:

> Confirmar reenvío del formularioEsta página web necesita los datos introducidos anteriormente para mostrarse correctamente. Puedes volver a enviar los datos, pero se repetirán las acciones que haya realizado la página.
> Pulsa el botón de actualización de página para que se vuelvan a enviar los datos necesarios para cargar la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando quiero actualizar la página web, se muestra una `alerta`:

> La página que buscas ha utilizado la información que has especificado. Volver a la página podría provocar la repetición de alguna acción. ¿Quieres continuar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si hago clic en el botón "Continuar", la tabla se vuelve a cargar perfectamente.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar la página web sin detenerme en la página o `alerta` "Confirmar reenvío del formulario"?

Probé con Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Check if the current URL contains '#'
    if (document.URL.indexOf("#") == -1) {
        // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
        url = document.URL + "#";
        location = "#";

        //Reload the page
        location.reload(true);
    }
});

location.reload(true);

window.onload = function () {
    if (!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Pero no funcionó. Me podrían ayudar con éste problema?

Comment: ¿Cómo llegas a "Vista 1"?  ¿Rellenas algun formulario para mostrar esa tabla o algo parecido?  Porque creo que lo que te está diciendo es que **antes** "Vista 1" ya venia de algun tipo de formulario y petición POST, y te está preguntando si quieres repetirlo antes de mostrar la página de la "Vista 1" ( y no si quieres enviar de nuevo los datos a "Vista 2"). ¿Tengo razón o voy equivocado?

Comment: Si tengo razón se me ocurre que en "Vista 2" pongas un boton (tipo formulario con campos hidden para hacer el POST) para regresar a "Vista 1" con los datos pasados por POST de nuevo.

Comment: exacto @masterguru, previo a vista 1 está la vista "Index", hago un filtro por fechas, y "Vista 1" son los datos traídos de la base de datos. En cuanto al botón, tambien lo estuve intentando, ya que es los datos de "Vista 1 " son una tabla, los estoy tratando de guardar dentro de una variable Global cuando paso a "Vista 2", y cuando vuelvo a "Vista 1", en vez de hacer la query denuevo, le paso la lista de una y asi evitar volver a preguntar a la bd.

Comment: Ya veo, pero no vas a solucionar el problema con la variable global, porque es el navegador que "recuerda" que venia de un POST en "Vista 1" y aunque en el código del servidor lo tengas cacheado de algun modo al navegador le da igual, el te va a preguntar si quieres o no mandarle esos datos. Insisto en que en "Vista 2" pongas ese botón y ya no te pasará. Por ejemplo: `<form action="miASPscript" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="fecha1" value="03/10/2022"><input type="hidden" name="fecha2" value="04/10/2022"><button type="submit">Regresar</button></form>`... algo así.

Comment: También podrias probar con `<button onclick="history.back()">Regresar</button>` a ver si cuela y no te pide el POST (quizás te muestre lo que ya tenias en cache en tu propio navegador, no estoy nada seguro)
`

Comment: Entiendo, Pero haciendo eso, estaría haciendo la query denuevo, o no?

Comment: Si, claro, pero dices que ya la tienes cacheada en tu PHP, por lo tanto no la harias de hecho, simplemente recogerias los datos de esa variable global que dices que guardas cosas.  No pasa nada tampoco por hacer la query de nuevo, las bases de datos estan para eso, pero si la consulta es lenta y por eso quieres cachearla entonces yo me miraria bien porque es lenta, pues no deben serlo e indican que algo está mal en el diseño de la consulta o de la propia tabla (indices y demas)

Comment: Otra solución seria usar AJAX para mostrar la "Vista 2" por encima de la "Vista 1" (en plan modal supongo) y cuando salieras de la "Vista 2" aún tendrias por debajo a la Vista 1 con los datos iniciales.

Comment: muy bien @masterguru, voy a poner en práctica los consejos que me diste y voy a hacer lo que me dijiste. El problema va a ser cuando el usuario no toque el <button> que yo le dé, sino cuando toque el retroceder del propio navegador, A menos que exista alguna forma de cancelarlo..

Comment: Bueno, si le da al boton retroceder no es tu problema. Eso pasa a menudo en muchas webs con formularios.  Y tan solo deben aceptar el reenvio de los datos. Lo que ya no tengo tan claro es si lo que hayas hecho (una actualización de datos, por ejemplo) en la "Vista 2" condiciona lo que se deba mostrar en "Vista 1" ante lo cual por narices mejor realizar de nuevo el POST y no recogerlo de ninguna cache.

Comment: No, de "Vista 2" a "Vista 1" no se modifican datos